# Python - ValueError: convert string to float with Regular expression module

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm running the following code:

```
import re
def extract_numbers(text):
    return [float(r.replace(',', '')) for r in re.findall(r'[\d,]+', text)]
```

This works for all samples, except the following:

```
  text = 'kjadhf asdf kjsadhf, alsdhf lksajdhf. lsad fjshdalf kjhsad f.'
```

I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I've restructured the code so it works for other text samples with numbers (text = '102 smse s', but does not work with no numbers in the sample.

Any suggestions on this issue would be appreciated!

Comment: Your RE will match the comma - i.e. ',' So, try this:- r'\d+[\d,]*'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression matches digits and commas, so in the string:

```
kjadhf asdf kjsadhf, alsdhf lksajdhf. lsad fjshdalf kjhsad f.
```

It matches `,`, which is then converted to an empty string, which can't be converted to a float.

There's many solutions to this, but one potential solution would be to start by looking for a digit and then keep any characters after that which are digits or commas. That way it would match `42`, `1,000,000`, etc but not `,`.

That would be achieved like this:

```py
import re
def extract_numbers(text):
    return [float(r.replace(',', '')) for r in re.findall(r'\d[\d,]*', text)]

print(extract_numbers("12Hello42World97"))
print(extract_numbers("HelloWorld1,234"))
print(extract_numbers(" 78 HelloWorld 32,852"))
print(extract_numbers("HelloWorld"))
print(extract_numbers("kjadhf asdf kjsadhf, alsdhf lksajdhf. lsad fjshdalf kjhsad f."))
```

That will output:

```
[12.0, 42.0, 97.0]
[1234.0]
[78.0, 32852.0]
[]
[]
```

An alternative solution would be to remove the commas from the original string and then you only need to look for digits:

```py
import re
def extract_numbers(text):
    return [float(r) for r in re.findall(r'\d+', text.replace(',', ''))]
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is raised when you attempt to create a float that does not contain a number. From what your question say, it appears that your method works when a string is passed in that contains a number value.

Notice the string that does not work does not contain any digits 0-9:

```
text = 'kjadhf asdf kjsadhf, alsdhf lksajdhf. lsad fjshdalf kjhsad f.'
```

Because it contains no digits, it raises this exception. You can change your method a few different ways depending on what you want it to do exactly.

Version 1: return none when the string passed in does not contain any digits

```
import re
def extract_numbers(text):
    try:
        return [float(r.replace(',', '')) for r in re.findall(r'[\d,]+', text)]
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Version 2: return -1 (or any number value you wish) when no digits are present in the string

```
import re
def extract_numbers(text):
    try:
        return [float(r.replace(',', '')) for r in re.findall(r'[\d,]+', text)]
    except ValueError:
        return -1
```

Version 3: Don't return anything at all.

```
import re
def extract_numbers(text):
    try:
        return [float(r.replace(',', '')) for r in re.findall(r'[\d,]+', text)]
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

It really depends on what you are trying to do with the value being returned. Any of these methods should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a little trick like adding a "0" string right before converting your string to a float. This way, the string will contain at least one digit (that would change the desired result) and won't allowed to float function to fail.

Try this code maybe:

```
import re
def extract_numbers(text):
    return [float("0" + r.replace(',', '')) for r in re.findall(r'[\d,]+', text)]

text = "kjadhf asdf kjsadhf, alsdhf lksajdhf. lsad fjshdalf kjhsad f."
print(extract_numbers(text))

>>> output :
[0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches a comma `,` even if there is no digit beside it.

You can try this.

```
import re
def extract_numbers(text):
    return [float(r.replace(',', '')) for r in re.findall(r'\d+[,\d]*', text)]


print(extract_numbers('kjadhf asdf kjsadhf, alsdhf 40,152lksajdhf. lsad fjshdalf kjhsad f.'))
print(extract_numbers('kjadhf asdf kjsadhf, alsdhf lksajdhf. lsad fjshdalf kjhsad f.'))
print(extract_numbers('205,152,200'))
print(extract_numbers(''))
print(extract_numbers('hi there9'))
```

```
[40152.0]
[]
[205152200.0]
[]
[9.0]
```